# Is it true that there is no concept of window in phantomJS, so "scrolling" doesn't exist in phantomJS?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, phantomjs, dom-events

I use python version 3.6 and selenium module version 3.4.1. I want my browser to occasionally scroll down and up for making the server to recognize it a real human user, not programmed one.

I set the widow-size, programmed scroll codes, and ran these. But when I saw the screenshot image in phantomJS, the image shows the the right 'width' but the 'full(infinite)-height' like a long sheet that shows all contents on the only one page.

After Googling, I found that phantomJS has no concept of window, 'scrollbar' related to the size of window, and actually It isn't possible to scroll down and up. Is It true?

If someone knows how to scroll, could they help me?
(p.s) I did not ask the code: `driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,some number);")`

Comment: Have you tried to scroll page over some time? I mean set a timeout.

Comment: Yes, I'd have tried scrolling and saving screenshots by each scrolling. Anyway, as we see no scrollbar in screenshot images however small size of height adjusted in a window-set code line, no changes occur in screenshot images - like a long sheet with flexible length according the amount of page's contents